# Is the other car there?

Tags: word-usage, usage

We have two cars. My brother had taken one and wasn't back yet. My dad wanted to go out. So he asked (because my mom wasn't home too):

> Is the other car there?

Does this sound fine?

P.S. And does "taken" in the description sound fine?

Comment: It's ok from a grammar point of view. It's quite informal. So a conversational use is fine.

Comment: What you father appears to be uncertain about is whether your mum is using the other car. If that were the case, the obvious question would be: **Does mum have the other car?** (although that's got nothing to do with grammar). The **too** at the end of your statement appears to refer to your brother's absence. It could be omitted or possibly replaced with **yet**, depending on your meaning.

Comment: So @Ronald  Sole Does my sentence work? And yes that "too" was referring to my brother's absence

Comment: As puppetsock says, the grammar's fine and it's colloquial. Whether you prefer a different sentence is simply a matter of choice

Comment: "My mom wasn't home _either_" = both brother and she were out.

Answer (score 1):

"My brother had taken one out, and wasn't back yet" would be more typical

"Is the other car still there?" would be more useful, or "Is the other car out there?"
but "Is the other car there?" is still fine

Comment: No, you don't need the out here.